# Read contents JSON file sitting on webserver from c# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json

I am trying to read the contents of a JSON file sitting in my github pages repository.

I can navigate and see the file contents in my browser if I specify the url.

If I use the code here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/397574/Use-Csharp-to-get-JSON-Data-from-the-Web-and-Map-i?msg=4615047#xx4615047xx

It claims to "just work", but it doesn't.

All I get back is:

```
<html><frameset><frame src="URL-TO-JSON-FILE"></frameset></html>
```

How am I supposed to read the json file and get its contents back as a string.  I am using c#?

Once I get the JSON string back I can do the processing I need to do in c#.

EDIT:
According to rawgithub.com those types of urls are not to be used for production. I need this for production. How do production website read remote JSON files that are located on a webserver?

Thank you

Comment: What do you see if you go to the URL and view source from the browser's menu (not by right-clicking on the content)?

Comment: I see the contents of the JSON file however I see in firebug that it is buried one layer down in the frameset.

Comment: Have you tried browsing raw.github/your-filename.json

Comment: @Andrew By the sounds of things, your code does actually work, you just have the URL wrong.

Comment: like so: <html>
<head></head>
<frameset>
<frame src="URL-TO-JSON-FILE">
<html>
<head>
<link title="Wrap Long Lines" href="resource://gre-resources/plaintext.css" type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<pre>{JSON-STRING}</pre>
</body>
<div id="sp_console_event" style="display:none"></div>
</html>
</frame>
</frameset>
<div id="sp_console_event" style="display:none"></div>
</html>

Comment: @Paul: what is that full raw.github url?

Comment: Just whatever url you are using but swap the subdomain (i.e. www) for raw

Comment: @Paul: my github repo is fullcirclesolutions.github.io. raw.fullcirclesolutions.github.io (and anything below it) returns 404.  Um, what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @PaulMcCowat:  according to rawgithub.com those types of urls are not to be used for production.  I need this for production.  How do production website read remote JSON files that are located on a webserver?

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcCowat, raw github url has done the trick.

Comment: No problem, sorry i couldn't help further yesterday, i was out.  Ill write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes in github, if you wish to use code from a repository, you must change the url to raw.github.com/ or click on the raw button and use this url.